# Math.SE Vs MathEducation.SE for questions about efficient structure of solutions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I’d like to reach out to the community to find an improved way of approaching a specific, common problem type (finding the Taylor coefficients in various binomial series expansions; both a) the general term and b) the first 4-5 nonzero terms).

I have been working on many of these problems recently, and my approach just feels inefficient. And although I have found questions on Math.SE about “solving more efficiently,”$^{\color{red}1}$ such questions clearly have a subjective element, and so seem in a bit of a grey area, in terms of being on-topic (although, when an answer is available, the Q&A together can provide a great practical resource, for many).

In addition to using this, personally, I would also want to share any great simplification with my students, so I wasn’t sure if this eventual end automatically framed it as a question for the Math Education SE, or if there is also room on Math.SE for asking about optimized methods / streamlining computations etc?

---

$^{\color{red}1}$: e.g. [the answer to this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/767316/179404) provides a really useful shortcut in the computation of finite binomial expansions.

Comment: As you are asking whether something is suitable for the Education site, shouldn't you be asking the people at the Education site?

Comment: I’m asking if it is suitable for the math.se site; hence a) posting here and b) the example of a similar question on the math.se site. Sorry if that wasn’t clear: if you can let me know what created the ambiguity, I will adjust the post to make it clearer.

Comment: The only question in your question is "I wasn’t sure if this eventual end automatically framed it as a question for the Math Education SE?" That sounds to me like you are asking whether the question is suitable for the Education site.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I can see that - I guess between the title,  the body of the text and the fact that I was posting on the math meta, I figured the second half of that final sentence was implied. I’ll add it explicitly. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 3):

My personal opinion is that as long as the question is framed in a mathematical way (or as a curious student might ask it) it is suitable for math.SE. In particular, your motivation for understanding the mathematics of a potentially elementary subject shouldn't have any bearing on its suitability-- if you are interested in a question about mathematics and ask the question in that light, then it seems to me appropriate.